# Как лучше всего отобразить большой текст?

Tags: android, android-fragment, webview, textview

Как поместить на фрагмент текст с большим объемом ? С помощью TextView или WebView ? Где-то тут прочитал, что при отображении большого текста с WebView будут лаги, так ли это ? Дайте советы. Таких фрагментов будет до 50 и текста будет больше.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы советовал воспользоваться `TextView` так как он проще по логике и не нужно много городить для поддержки, а так же у него есть много параметров для показа большого текста, вот например:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

[вот](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) доки по данному виджету. Так же можно добавить расположение виджета, чтобы он заполнял экран:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

Можно указывать много параметров которые направлены на обработку и показ большого текста.

### UPDATE

как было правильно замечено в комментариях, у данного вью элемента есть очень полезный аттрибут:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

который позволит скролить ваш textView.

Comment: + можно засунуть TextView в HorisontalScrollView. И можно будет листать его хоть до бесконечности

Comment: да, спасибо за уточнение))) думал за это, но что-то пошло не так и не написал)) вообще не обязательно мне кажется именно horisontal, все зависит от того куда нужно скроллить)

Comment: Не нужно никуда его класть. Ставьте атрибут android:scrollbars = "vertical", и ваша вьюшка будет скролится без лишних ViewGroup и без рендеринга огромного TextView

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, да вы правы у этой вьюхи есть свои скролы тоже, вариантов вообще масса)

Comment: Не совсем согласен... Правильным видится именно вариант с атрибутом. Если вы пихаете обычный TextView в ScrollView, то отрендерится огромная вьюшка со всем включенным в нее текстом. Если текста правда много, можно и по памяти не влезть =) А когда вы ставите скролбар в саму TextView. то она на этапе рендеринга выдаст вьюшку ровно того размера, сколько занимает на экране, ни больше ни меньше. Это явно предпочтительнее по памяти и производительности